# Android Appcompat Toolbar Title not shown correctly

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I am using support Toolbar from version suppport lib `25.0.1` and randomly it shows like this:

[image]

Now this is random and I dont know how to reproduce this. Some times it shows ok some times doesnt show correctly.

This is how I use the Toolbar in my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Toolbar"
    android:elevation="@dimen/toolbar_elevation"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.App.Toolbar.Popup"/>

<style name="Theme.App.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**Fragment:**

```
toolbar.setTitle("Story title");
appCompatActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

As it can be seen from the screeenshot somehow the toolbar tries to put the subtitle but I dont have one.

Is this happening to other people, is this a known bug for this problem, any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for me until now is to use support library version `25.0.0`

Other solutions or updates are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme"
    tools:ignore="NewApi">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here you can set title gravity to left.

Then access it in the code like this way:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_toolbar);
tvToolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tv_title_toolbar);
tvToolbarTitle.setText(title);
```

Comment: I dont want to customize that, imagine for an existing project you will have to go everywhere and set text title instead of toolbar.setTitle. And I am sure in the future this will be fixed

Comment: yeah, in the meanwhile either you have to stick with older version of support library 25.0.0 or you can customize the toolbar with above solution